# Hard sci-fi novel where the protagonist uses a wormhole portal and discovers a second version of themself

Tags: story-identification, novel, hard-sci-fi, wormhole

Hard sci-fi novel. Protagonist uses a wormhole portal and discovers a second version of herself (sister? clone?). May also feature tree-like alien life forms.

Comment: That is as vague as "looking for a sf book about a robot and fantasy book with elf in it." Anyway, check does anything on this list look familiar https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AlternateSelf

Comment: Reminds me of Proxima, by Stephen Baxter. I recall Stef the scientist suddenly gains a twin-sister when she accesses the wormhole portal entrance found beneath the surface of Mercury. The twig like aliens are called weavers.

Comment: Proxima! That's it! To those for whom the clue was insufficient, if I had more, I likely would have been able to locate without help... Thanks Handsome Jim!

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by user Handsome Jim and confirmed by the OP in comments above, this is *[Proxima](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1616089)* (2013) by Stephen Baxter.

Per the blurb on [the book's goodreads.com page](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/17983396-proxima):

> The very far future: The galaxy is a drifting wreck of black holes,
> neutron stars, and chill white dwarfs. The age of star formation is
> long past. Yet there is life here, feeding off the energies of the
> stellar remnants, and there is mind, a tremendous galaxy-spanning
> intelligence each of whose thoughts lasts a hundred thousand years.
> And this mind cradles memories of a long-gone age when a more compact
> universe was full of light... The 27th century: Proxima Centauri, an
> undistinguished red dwarf star, is the nearest star to our sun. How
> would it be to live on such a world?